# Passing UIImage to second view controller lags transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using a UIImagePickerController to select an image from my photo album. Once I've selected the image, I'm passing the image through to a second view controller and displaying it in a UIImageView. See code below:

First view controller:

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto
{
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    UploadViewController *uploadViewController = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViewController" bundle:nil];
    [uploadViewController setImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];

    [picker pushViewController:uploadViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Second view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the image view image
    imageView.image = self.image;
}
```

The code does the job, however, when I push from the image picker to my second view controller, it lags as it's transitioning.

Ideally I would like a smooth transition but I would be happy if it just waited half a second or something and then moves smoothly.

Can any explain why this could be happening and how/if I can get around it?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to push controller on imagePicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay is probably from rendering the image, you could try having your UploadViewController's initial view contain an activity spinner then actually set the image in the viewDidAppear method, this method should be called after the animation is completed.

Comment: This method did mean I get a smooth transition, but then it sits and waits for the image to load. Is there any way I get sit and wait for the image to load before the transition? So that way when you push to the new view, the image is already there and it slides smoothly?

Comment: One thing I have noticed in iOS is that drawing images is a time consuming process which is made worse by the fact the images in the photo library are often much higher resolution than is needed for display in an app. One thing I did in one of my apps to help speed up the process is scale down the image before drawing it on the screen. You should probably check the app in Instruments to see where the time is spent but if its drawing related scaling down may help.

Comment: You were spot on with the image resizing. I totally forgot that the image would be several thousand by several thousand pixels. I used the image resizing category sample from: http://ofcodeandmen.poltras.com/2008/10/30/undocumented-uiimage-resizing/ to resize to 960x640 and it loads perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Resizing the image will fix the issue. The effect is exactly what you want, wait half a second on the UIImagePickerController then move smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this , here timer is introduced in order to provide delay(0.5sec) ,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    [NSTimerscheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:info repeats:NO];
}


-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  UploadViewController *uploadViewController = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViewController" bundle:nil];
    [uploadViewController setImage:[[timer userInfo]objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]];

    [picker pushViewController:uploadViewController animated:YES];
   [uploadViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it didn't fix the problem. The transition was delayed for half a second, but then it still lagged during the transition.

Comment: have you tried above code? I hope you have replaced [picker pushe...] with [self push..]?

Comment: Yeh I've tried the code, I replaced the [picker pushe...] with [imagePicker pushe...] as that's the property I'm using for my image picker. The timer delayed the transition, but when the transition took place, it was still lagging.

Comment: Of course that doesn't work. You're doing the exact same thing, just later. However, you did fix a memory leak. :)